# multiple onload error in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:-

In the body tag I have used `onload="variable2.init() ; variable1.init();"`.

JavaScript:-

```
var variable1 = {
rssUrl: 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/football-italia/pAjS',

init: function() {
    this.getRSS();
},

getRSS: function() {
    jQuery.getFeed({
        url: variable1.rssUrl,
        success: function showFeed(feed) {
            variable1.parseRSS(feed);
        }
    });
},

parseRSS: function(feed) {
    var main = '';
    var posts = '';
    var className = 'even';
    var pst = {};
    for (i = 0; i < feed.items.length; i++) {
        pst = variable1.parsefootballitaliaRSS(feed.items[i]);
        if (className == 'odd') {
            className = 'even';
        }
        else {
            className = 'odd';
        }
        var shorter = pst.story.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
        item_date = new Date(feed.items[i].updated);
        main += '<div id="content1" class="post-main ' + className + '" onclick="mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens1\', \'#blog_posts1\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#blog_posts1\', \'#post' + (i+1) + '\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');">';
        main += '<b>' + pst.title.trunc(55, true) + '</b><br />' + shorter.trunc(30, true);
        main += '<div class="datetime">' + item_date.getDateTime() + '</div></div>';

        posts += '<div class="post-wrapper ui-hide" id="post' + (i+1) + '">';
        posts += '<div class="post-title"><b>' + pst.title + '</b></div>';
        posts += feed.items[i].description;
        posts += '</div>';
    }

    jQuery('#main_screen1').html(main);
    jQuery('#blog_posts1').html(posts);

},

parsefootballitaliaRSS: function(item) {
    var match = item.description.match('src="([^"]+)"');
    var part = item.description.split('<font size="-1">');
    var arr = {
        title: item.title,
        link: item.link,
        image: match,
        site_title: item.title,
        story: item.description
    };

    return arr;
}
};

var variable2 = {
    weatherRSS: 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/go/ELkW',

    init: function() {
        this.getWeatherRSS();
    },

    getWeatherRSS: function() {
        jQuery.getFeed({
            url: variable2.weatherRSS,
            success: function showFeed(feed) {
                variable2.parseWeather(feed);
            }
        });
    },

    parseWeather: function(feed) {
        var main = '';
        var posts = '';
        var className = 'even';
        var pst = {};
        for (i = 0; i < feed.items.length; i++) {
            pst = variable2.parsegoRSS(feed.items[i]);
            if (className == 'odd') {
                className = 'even';
            }
            else {
                className = 'odd';
            }
            var shorter = pst.story.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
            item_date = new Date(feed.items[i].updated);
            main += '<div id="content2" class="post-main ' + className + '" onclick="mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens2\', \'#blog_posts2\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#blog_posts2\', \'#post' + (i+1) + '\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');">';
            main += '<b>' + pst.title.trunc(55, true) + '</b><br />' + shorter.trunc(30, true);
            main += '<div class="datetime">' + item_date.getDateTime() + '</div></div>';

            posts += '<div class="post-wrapper ui-hide" id="post' + (i+1) + '">';
            posts += '<div class="post-title"><b>' + pst.title + '</b></div>';
            posts += feed.items[i].description;
            posts += '</div>';
        }

        jQuery('#main_screen2').html(main);
        jQuery('#blog_posts2').html(posts);

    },

    parsegoRSS: function(item) {
        var match = item.description.match('src="([^"]+)"');
        var part = item.description.split('<font size="-1">');
        var arr = {
            title: item.title,
            link: item.link,
            image: match,
            site_title: item.title,
            story: item.description
        };

        return arr;
    }
};
```

When I run the program it only reads one of the variables i.e. either 1 or 2.
How can I correct them to read both the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body onload="callFunctions()">
```

**JS-**

```
function callFunctions()
{
variable1.init(); 
variable2.init();
}
```

**Update-**

Also
**[there are other different ways to call multiple functions on page load](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm)**

Hope it hepls you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {  

  variable1.init(); 
  variable2.init();

 }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the above code in html only but still there is a problem. Do we need to use window.onload code in js file too?

Comment: @user2326438 You add external js files?.

Comment: @user2326438 ok. then you want to add window.onload in js files.

Comment: yes because I added the above code in the HTML file but it reads either variable1 or variable2.

Comment: I am using a List item tree layout to create a mobile application. Here when i click on item-1 it should read variable1 which includes blog link 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/football-italia/pAjS' similarly i am trying to do that for item-2 but when i use both variable1 and variable2 in HTML it leads to a problem.